# Best way to draw a circle with OpenGL ES 2.0 / cocos2d 2.0?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, glsl, opengl-es-2.0, shader

What is the best way to draw circles with OpenGL ES 2.0?

I am working on an iPad/iPhone project using cocos2d 2.0 (currently beta) which uses OpenGL ES 2.0 and shaders instead of OpenGL ES 1.0.

In my former projects I used that handy class ColoredCircleSprite that is included in the SneakyInput package. But now with OpenGL ES 2.0 that code is not working anymore and to be honest I am a little lost here in writing my own solution from scratch. I need a CCSprite subclass that draws smooth circles. (Perhaps with a little shadow shader...)

Should I build a rectangular shape in the vertex shader and then discard every pixel outside the circle radius in the fragment shader? Or should I build the circle vertices inside the vertex shader?

Are there any good tutorials about this topic on the net? As OpenGL-n00b I would appreciate every kind of help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ccDrawCircle](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/_c_c_drawing_primitives_8h.html#a34d0ad7b8f0d0dbd5fb874d607d69f1d):

```
ccDrawCircle(CGPoint center, float radius, float angle, 
             NSUInteger segments, BOOL drawLineToCenter);
```

Increase the number of segments to make the circle smoother. Have a look at the implementation of ccDrawCircle in CCDrawingPrimitives.h if you want to learn from the code.

Comment: Thanks, but: this method was already present in cocos2d 1.0. Is it really optimized for OpenGL ES 2.0? Does it use shaders?

Comment: These methods aren't really "optimized", they probably don't support shaders in cocos2d 2.0. They're mainly used to draw debug information.

Comment: `drawCircle` can't even draw a smooth circle